# Traversing an html nested list, follow-up question - detecting a node's position

Tags: javascript, dom, traversal

With reference to to an previous question of mine:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052414/traversing-an-html-nested-list-using-javascript)

I have an additional question, as follows:

I need the ability to start the "position" at a point within the tree. Users can select a node within the tree by way of a hash (e.g. #post9) - they can click a node anywhere in the list to select it, or they can bookmark the url, which would include that node's own hash.

So my further question is: how would I locate a node within the tree and get it's position, using the hash in the URL? The hash in the URL correlates with the id of the `<li>` node.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Position as in index or position as in offset in pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.location.hash` to get the element, find it and then use `index()` on your list of `<li>` elements to get its index/position.

```
var node = $(window.location.hash),
    index = $('li').index(node);
```

Comment: Terrific - thank you very much, everything is working beautifully now